# Can not run jar file on websphere

Tags: java, websphere, redhat

I had problem with Websphere.
I want to run test.jar in websphere.

I copy test.jar in dropins and run "sh ./server start --archive="java -jar ../dropins/test.jar"
Starting server --> ok
But console.log empty

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this is a SpringBoot application JAR?    Otherwise you would generally need to deploy a WAR or EAR file to the server rather than a JAR.   You can package the server itself as a runnable JAR though.   Is this WebSphere Liberty?  Some more detail would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your description exactly what you're trying to do, but based on your title, I assume you're trying to run a Java application.  Liberty is an app server for running Java EE apps, but given that you're trying to run a file ending in .jar, that is more typical of a standalone (Java SE) app.  Also, the command line you're using is mixing options, the --archive option is for specifying a target file for the server package or dump operation.  See the IBM help topic https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=line-server-command-options for more details.  On the Liberty app server, you can deploy Java EE (not Java SE) apps by copying the .ear or .war of the app to the dropins directory.  If you provide additional details about the contents of test.jar and what you're trying to achieve, you'll get a more complete answer.